# Haskell introspecting a record's field names and types

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Based on a [recent exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659939/haskell-setting-record-field-based-on-field-name-string), I've been convinced to use Template Haskell to generate some code to ensure compile-time type safety.

I need to introspect record field names and types. I understand I can [get field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457876/get-a-haskell-records-field-names-as-a-list-of-strings) by using `constrFields . toConstr :: Data a => a -> [String]`. But I need more than the field names, I need to know their type. For example, I need to know the names of fields that are of type `Bool`.

How do I construct a function `f :: a -> [(String, xx)]` where `a` is the record, `String` is the field name and `xx` is the field type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The type should be available, along with everything else, in the `Info` value provided by `reify`. Specifically, you should get a `TyConI`, which contains [a `Dec` value](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/2.6.0.0/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH.html#t%3aDec), from which you can get the list of [`Con` values specifying the constructors](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/2.6.0.0/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH.html#t%3aCon). A record type should then use `RecC`, which will give you a list of fields [described by a tuple](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/2.6.0.0/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#t%3aVarStrictType) containing the field name, whether the field is strict, and [the type](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/2.6.0.0/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#t%3aType).

Where you go from there depends on what you want to do with all this.

---

**Edit**: For the sake of actually demonstrating the above, here's a really terrible quick and dirty function that finds record fields:

```
import Language.Haskell.TH

test :: Name -> Q Exp
test n = do rfs <- fmap getRecordFields $ reify n
            litE . stringL $ show rfs

getRecordFields :: Info -> [(String, [(String, String)])]
getRecordFields (TyConI (DataD _ _ _ cons _)) = concatMap getRF' cons
getRecordFields _ = []

getRF' :: Con -> [(String, [(String, String)])]
getRF' (RecC name fields) = [(nameBase name, map getFieldInfo fields)]
getRF' _ = []

getFieldInfo :: (Name, Strict, Type) -> (String, String)
getFieldInfo (name, _, ty) = (nameBase name, show ty)
```

Importing that in another module, we can use it like so:

```
data Foo = Foo { foo1 :: Int, foo2 :: Bool }

foo = $(test ''Foo)
```

Loading that in GHCi, the value in `foo` is `[("Foo",[("foo1","ConT GHC.Types.Int"),("foo2","ConT GHC.Types.Bool")])]`.

Does that give you the rough idea?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for. I boiled your example down to the following: `introspect n = reify n >>= stringE . show`. Thanks for the guidance!